# Custom Google Search doesn't appear on IE8 and IE9

Tags: javascript, html

We recently updated our search engine on Google to a custom search. It works fine on Chrome, Firefox and Safari but the search field window doesn't appear in IE8 & IE9. I checked the CSS to see if that was the problem but it doesn't seem to be the issue.

Here is the script that they want us to use, doesn't anyone see an issue for why it wouldn't appear in IE?

```
<!-- The following javascript appears before the closing </head> tag. -->
<script>
(function() {
var cx = '012938749785999463601:bae5a4ajf2q';
var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>
<!-- This tag is inserted where the search box should render -->
 <gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

Here is a site page: http://amazingribs.com/tips_and_technique/index2.html

This code works in every other browser. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try moving the code somewhere inside the `<body>` tags?

You have it in the `<head>` tags, but it refers to `document`, which might not be "ready" at the time the script executes. By placing it in `<body>`, `document` should be available.

Also, I would try changing this:

> var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);

To just this:

> document.body.appendChild(gcse);

Comment: I tried moving the script down into the HTML body and it does show up in IE now. Do know of any detractions to this method? The Google code requests that we insert it in the <head> section.

Comment: I can't think of any issues that would occur by moving the script. As long as it works in all the major browsers!

Comment: I moved the script into the Body section and it now works in IE8 and IE9. Google offers two different versions of each search element v1 and v2. V2 is designed to go into the <head> and v1 is designed to go into the <body>. V1 code is much larger. V2 is short. I don't know the reason for the size difference. But the V2 code seems to still work when inserted in the <body>.